# Update UI after sending POST request on Angular 13

Tags: angular, firebase, post, fetch

I have a method to post data and another one to fetch data, each one on it's current button and function. What I'm trying to achieve is to update the posts array when clicking on Send Post.
My aproach was to call onFetchPosts in the same function in which I created them, each function works as a unit, but when I tried to call fetch on create, it just wont work

````
Html File Using Bootstrap 4 and angular template driven forms

    ``` <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <form #postForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onCreatePost(postForm.value)">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="title"
            required
            ngModel
            name="title"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="content">Content</label>
          <textarea
            class="form-control"
            id="content"
            required
            ngModel
            name="content"
          ></textarea>
        </div>
        <button
          class="btn btn-primary"
          type="submit"
          [disabled]="!postForm.valid"
        >
          Send Post
        </button>
      </form>
      </div>
     </div>
     <hr />
     <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onFetchPosts()">
        Fetch Posts
      </button>
      |
      <button
        class="btn btn-danger"
        [disabled]="loadedPosts.length < 1"
        (click)="onClearPosts()"
      >
        Clear Posts
      </button>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <p *ngIf="loadedPosts.length < 1 && !isFetching">No posts available!</p>
      <ul class="list-group" *ngIf="loadedPosts.length >= 1 && !isFetching">
        <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let post of loadedPosts">
          <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
          <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="loading-spinner" *ngIf="isFetching">
        <div class="sk-chase">
          <div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
          <div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
          <div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
          <div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
          <div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
          <div class="sk-chase-dot"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div> ```

Ts File, calling the functions made in the service.ts file

    ``` import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Post } from './post.model';  
    import { PostsService } from './posts.service';

    @Component({
     selector: 'app-post',
     templateUrl: './post.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./post.component.scss']
     })
    export class PostComponent implements OnInit {
   loadedPosts: Post[] = [];
   isFetching = false;

   constructor(private http: HttpClient, private postsService: PostsService) { }

   ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isFetching = true;
    this.postsService.fetchPosts().subscribe(posts => {
      this.isFetching = false;
      this.loadedPosts = posts;
    });
   }

   // Here I'm trying to call fetchPosts after I create one, but the UI won't get updated
   onCreatePost(postData: { title: string; content: string }) {
   this.isFetching = true;
    this.postsService.createAndStorePost(postData.title, postData.content) 
   this.postsService.fetchPosts().subscribe(posts => {
      this.isFetching = false;
      this.loadedPosts = posts;
     });
   }

  onFetchPosts() {
    // Send Http request
    this.isFetching = true;
    this.postsService.fetchPosts().subscribe(posts => {
      this.isFetching = false;
      this.loadedPosts = posts;
     });
     }

    onClearPosts() {
    // Send Http request
    this.postsService.deletePosts().subscribe(() => {
      this.loadedPosts = [];
    });
    }
    } ```

Service.ts, creating functions to create, fetch and delete posts

``` import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

import { Post } from "./post.model";

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class PostsService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
    createAndStorePost(title: string, content: string) {
        const postData: Post = {title: title, content: content};
        this.http
        .post<{ name: string }>(
          'https://to my backend at.firebaseio.com/posts.json',
          postData
        )
        .subscribe(responseData => {
          console.log(responseData);
        });
    }
    
    fetchPosts() {
        return this.http
            .get<{ [key: string]: Post }>(
                'https://to my backend at.firebaseio.com/posts.json'
                )
            .pipe(
                map(responseData => { 
                    const postsArray: Post[] = [];
                    for (const key in responseData) {
                    if (responseData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        postsArray.push({ ...responseData[key], id: key });
                    }     
                }
                return postsArray;
            })
        );
    }

    deletePosts() {
        return this.http.delete('https://to my backend at.firebaseio.com/posts.json')
    }
} ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to subscribe in service. Instead do this

```
createAndStorePost(title: string, content: string) {
    const postData: Post = { title: title, content: content };
    return this.http
        .post<{ name: string }>(
            'https://to my backend at.firebaseio.com/posts.json',
            postData
        );
}
```

And then in you component

```
onCreatePost(postData: { title: string; content: string }) {
    this.isFetching = true;
    this.postsService.createAndStorePost(postData.title, postData.content).subscribe(()=>{
        this.isFetching = false;
        this.onFetchPosts();
    });
}
```